SSL certificate on docker hosted website like open-webui
So I have a domain at porkbun which have given me an SSL cert. But now I want to put a SSL certificate on the website. The server is hosted on a mini pc and the website on localhost, then open-webui I have forwarded to port 80 on router and I have done the DNS and everything. Website is working on my domain it's just not https only http.
I am not that familiar with Docker so I won't know how to do stuff like editing an image or container but I will learn.
I have tried different DNS records, I have tried getting the cert inside the container in a way with a script thing I found on the internet. That's it, can't find anything else.

You might want to look into http proxy.
You can run your docker container and map it on a port, let's say 5000, like this:
Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["curl", "-s", "http://example.com"]

Then run the container, let's say you are using docker compose, like this:
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  example:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:80"

And then you install a webserver (I show you how to do that on apache, but many others work as well - I think most common would be nginx).
First you install apache (this is an example for ubuntu/debian):
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2


allow it on the firewall:

sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'


enable mod proxy and mod proxy http modules:

sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http


apache stores the configuration files of virtual hosts under /etc/apache2/sites-available

you want to edit the default page:
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

or
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

replace the default entry with:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your-domain.com
</VirtualHost>


install certbot

sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-apache


activate the domain in webserver

a2ensite 000-default.conf


run certbot

certbot

Follow the instructions (I like to redirect from port 80 to 443 automatically).
It will create a file called 000-default-le-ssl.conf - that should look like this then:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName your-domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/your-domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/your-domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>


where you want to add something:

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/



and then you just need to restart your apache server

sudo systemctl restart apache2

-- Or you might want to have a look into nginx proxy manager if you need alot of them.
Btw. it is also good practice to create a cron job for renewal
Open the root users crontab and add a line:
sudo crontab -e

and add
0 2 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew --quiet

hope that helps
If you want to use the certifcate that was given to you, you may add the -le-ssl.conf manually, a2ensite it as well and add the certifcates somewhere on the server and add the location of the certifcates to the path in the default-le-ssl.conf
